# How to Click Excel Custom Tab Control using VB Script only, so that i can use it in UFT

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2010, windows-shell

There is custom tab in excel file.In which we need to click on specific control using VB script.Tried with commandbars as per microsoft examples.It works fine for inbuild tabs but not custom tab and controls.

Based on MS portal commandbars(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbar) has been suspended, need to use iribbonUI but there is no where how to use it VBScript.

There is any way to do using windows shell?

The below is the reference for custom tabs created in excel https://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html

Let me know how we can use iribbonUI using vbscript.So that i can use it for UFT tool

Comment: What does this has to do with the Windows Shell? What is the Windows Shell for you?

Comment: if there is no way with VB script  atleast with shell script we can achieve it or not?